# How in laravel query builder, get count of child rows that meet a certain condition, for each record in parent table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a `users` table and a `messages` table that stores messages that users send to each other.
users table:

```
-------------------
|id|name  |lastName|
|------------------|
|1 |emma  |watson  |
|2 |taylor|swift   |
|3 |tiger |woods   |
```

massages table:

```
|id|messageBody|from_id|to_id|isRead|
|-----------------------------------|
|1 |...        |1      |2    |0     |
|2 |...        |2      |3    |1     |
|3 |...        |1      |3    |0     |
```

what I seek is to get the list of all users and count of unread messages that they have send to current user,which in laravel is reached by auth()->user().
I realized that sql query for this is sth like this:

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,users.lastName,(select count(*)
from messages where messages.from_id = users.id and messages.to_id =1 and 
messages.isRead = 0) as countOfNewMessages FROM users
```

but how can I reach this result with laravel's query builder?

Comment: Do you have to use the query builder? Or can you use Eloquent relationships?

Answer (score 1):

The classic method is

```
// messages
$messages = Messages::where('isRead',0)->where('to_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();

//count of messages

$count = $messages->count();
```

But you also can use `relations` to get messages of users and their count.
Please follow [Laravel:Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

On your Messages Model

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','to_id','id');
}
```

On your Controller

```
//For All Data
$messages = Messages::with('user')->where(['isRead'=>0,'to_id'=>1])->get();
//For Count Data
you can easily check how much unread message by `count($messages)`
```